Understanding File Access in Databricks File System (DBFS) versus Volumes with Python and Spark
I am currently trying to read and display a file from the Databricks File System (DBFS), but I encountered an issue. Here is the code I was using:
file_path = "/dbfs/cluster-logs/use_case/default_job_cluster/cluster_id/init_scripts/cluster_id/20240801_proxy-init.sh.stderr.log"

with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    contents = file.read()
    print(contents)

However, interestingly I get the following error:
bash: line 11: /Volumes/landing/default/artifacts/projects/use_case/databricks/scripts/proxy-init.sh: No such file or directory

As you can see the path did not match the original input.
In the end, I was able to correctly read and display the log file content with the following code:
file_path = "/dbfs/cluster-logs/use_case/default_job_cluster/cluster_id/init_scripts/cluster_id/20240801_proxy-init.sh.stderr.log"

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list

if dbutils.fs.ls(file_path):
    file_df_to_check = spark.read.text(file_path).agg(collect_list("value").alias("all_lines"))
    display(file_df_to_check)

Questions:

Why does the first code snippet produce an error referring to the volume path?
What does it mean in the documentation that DBFS provides a scheme for volumes? Shouldnt the first snipped work then?
Why can the file only be read using Spark and not with the standard Python open function?

Thank you for your assistance.


Can you post full error message you get with first code block? 2. file_path = ... line is missing from the second code block, add that.


The full error message in block 1 is already given. 2. I updated the second code block. It is the same path as in 1.

python code you posted will not produce the error message you posted. anyway, all the best..

Probably depends on how volumes are configured in your set up. Thank you
